# C++ read data from a file and create an asteriks bar chart

Tags: c++, vector, graph, ifstream, ofstream

For my assignment I've been asked to do this:

> Read sales values from a file called ‘sales.txt’ and outputs a bar graph representing these values to a file called ‘graph.txt’. Create each bar in the bar graph by displaying a row of asterisks. Each asterisk should represent £100 of sales.
>   The sales values are:

```
1000
500
1200
600
200
```

The graph should look like this:

```
SALES BAR CHART
(each * equals £100)
Store 1: **********
Store 2: *****
Store 3: ************
Store 4: ******
Store 5: **
```

This is the code I have done so far:

```
#pragma once //stops duplicate library 
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class SalesData
{
private:
ifstream inputfile;
ofstream outputfile;
vector<int> salesrecord;

public:

void loadDataFromFile(string filename);
void saveBarChartToFile(string filename);
};

void SalesData::loadDataFromFile(string filename)
{
ifstream sales;
sales.open("Sales.txt",ios::in);

cout << "opening file." << endl; 

sales.close(); 
}

void SalesData::saveBarChartToFile(string filename)
{

ofstream graph;
graph.open("Graph.txt", ios::out);

graph << "SALES BAR CHART" << endl;
graph << " (each * equals £100)" << endl;

graph.close();
}

int main()
{
vector<int> salesrecord(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
{
    salesrecord[i] = i;
}
SalesData Mydata;

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing your issue?

Comment: If your program works correctly and you want to know about performance issues, post to SoftwareRecs@StackExchange.com

Comment: Please **edit** your post with a sample of the input file.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file struct".

Comment: BTW, the variable `salesrecord` in `main()` is not the same as the variable `salesrecords` in your class `SalesData`.  By the way, differentiating variables by one letter is evil and can lead to injecting defects (for example, forgetting the trailing "s").

Comment: The code you posted is missing elements to read in the data as well as drawing the chart.

Comment: Have you talked with your instructor about how to complete the assignment?  I recommend you discuss the issue with your instructor first.

Comment: I've asked my instructor for assistance but he told me that he's not allowed to help anymore than he already has. I was just wondering what sections of code I was missing